# Arduino restarts after serial input from Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, linux, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have this code running on the arduino:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// pins!!!!
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
const int delayTime=10;

const int pin_yes_gate=3;
const int pin_no_gate=5;

int switchVal =0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial port to send and receive at 9600 baud
  pinMode(pin_yes_gate, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_no_gate, OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
{
    if (switchVal ==1 ){
      allow();
    }else{
      prohibit();
    }

  if ( Serial.available())
  {
    String string = Serial.readString();
    string.trim();
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.print(string);
    Serial.print("\n");

    if(string.equals("allowed"))
    {
      switchVal=1;
    }else if(string.equals("error"))
    {
      switchVal=0;
    }
  }
}

void allow(){
  digitalWrite(pin_yes_gate,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pin_no_gate,LOW);
  delay(delayTime);
}

void prohibit(){
  digitalWrite(pin_yes_gate,LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin_no_gate,HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);
}
```

and I'm writing `echo allowed >> /dev/ttyACM0` which gives the reaction, but for less than a second, and then the arduino returns to the initial state. This is weird, as it works with the arduino IDE perfectly.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: The only thing I wonder about is what effect the `delay(delayTime);` is supposed to have and if there could be a problem if you repeatedly do those `digitalWrite`s. What if you remove the `if (switchVal ==1 ){ ... } else { ... }` part and call `allow` and `prohibit` directly when the strings are received? `if(string.equals("allowed")) allowed(); else if(string.equals("error")) prohibit();` In that case, you can also remove both `delay`s.

Comment: @TedLyngmo delay is needed, there, as the system that takes signals has requested the delay. I have solved it below.... so trivial yet took me ages

Comment: "_the system that takes signals has requested the delay_" - The system that receives the signals will not notice if the delay is removed if you do the things I suggested before that. It will only toggle the pins as fast as you can type `error` in 9600 bps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it, apparently the problem is the

```cpp
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.print(string);
    Serial.print("\n");
```

It errors out if serial is not read. So either removing this, or as in my case I can't change anything on the arduino side run this command on raspi boot `tail -f /dev/ttyACM0 &` which opens a read port